Binomial Test for data with normally distributed messurement error
I have a series of measurements and I want to perform a binomial test to see if the chance of exceeding some value $a$ is less or equal to some $p_0$. The measurement has some error which is normally distributed. This means for every measurement I have a normal distribution which gives the probability of the true value. This normal distribution is a bit different for every measurement, but it is known and for every measurement I could compute a number $x_i$ such that the probability that the true value of this measurement is less or equal than $a$ equals $x_i$. Is there a possibility to perform a binomial test (or something similar) to see that the probability for a true value to be higher than $a$ is less or equal to some $p_0$ if I assume that the measurement errors are independent.
And how does the situation change if the error for the different measurements would not be independent, but I could divide the error in two parts. I have one part which comes from the calibration, so it is the same for all measurements and the other part comes from the uncertainties when performing that exact measurement, so this is independent for the different measurement.

Hey Adrian, I'm struggling to follow this. You have some IID quantities $X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim F_X$ (the true values) and are interested in whether the probability $\overline{F}_X(a)=\Pr(X>a)$ is less than or equal to $p_0$. You don't actually observe the true values; instead, you observe $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$, where $Y_i=X_i+\epsilon_i$, where $\epsilon_i \sim \mathrm{N}(0, \sigma_i^2)$. Is this correct?

Yes that is correct

What do you know about the $\sigma^2_i$?

It is known for every $i$. But in general, they are not identical for $i\neq j$
